# Discrete Mathematics proving set equality

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Refer to this Definition to solve the problem bolded:

If $f : X \to Y$ is a function and $A \subseteq X$ and $C \subset Y$ , then
$f (A) = \{y \in Y\, |\, y = f (x)\text{ for some }x \in A\}$
and $f^{−1}(C) = \{x \in X\, |\, f (x) \in C\}$.
$f (A)$ is called the image of $A$, and $f^{−1}(C)$ is called the inverse image of $C$.

**For all subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$, Prove or Disprove:
$F(A \cap B) = F(A) \cap F(B)$**

I am completely lost and have no idea how to approach this problem.
I'm guessing I have to prove that the LHS and RHS are both proper subsets of each other to show equality. Any help is welcome to get me started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true. Let

$A = \{1,2\}$,

$B=\{4,5\}$,

$f(1) = 2$, $f(2) = 3$, $f(4) = 3$, $f(5) = 4$.

Then $A \cap B = \emptyset$, so $f(A \cap B) = \emptyset$. But

$f(A) = \{2,3\}$  ;   $f(B) = \{3,4\}$

So $f(A) \cap f(B) = \{3\}$, which is not empty.

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could figure out the solving methods as I am still in the dark on how to approach these.

Comment: Well, the trick here was to just take $A$ and $B$ to be non-overlapping. This guarantees that $f(A \cap B) = \emptyset$. Then you just have to rig the function so that the images of $A$ and $B$ **are** overlapping. Draw pictures.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand it better with your tip about drawing it out.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the two sides are not equal.Let A = (-1, 0 ], and B = (0, 1], X = Y = [-1, 1] and F:X --> Y as F(x) = x^2 ,then F(A and B) = empty , while F(A) intersects F(B) is not empty. In general, the LHS is a subset of the RHS.